# When did chapter and verse numbers start being used?

Tags: history, versification

In the gospels (and other places) there are quotes of other books of the Bible but only  the text with no numeric references e.g. (John 1:1).

In Jesus's time and before, a quote by anybody did not include where it came from.

Now, when somebody quotes a book of the bible, it includes a reference to the book, chapter and verse it comes from.

I was wondering, from a historical point of view, how these precise references came to be.

When did these references start being used?

Comment: Do you mean the margin references in some Bibles or something else?

Comment: An example (Jn 10:34) Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, Ye are gods? He quotes but doesn't say where exactly it comes from. Where did the references of book, chapter and verse start?

Comment: Bible chapters were added in the 12th century and verse numbers were added for the 1560 edition of the Geneva Bible.

Comment: It would help if you could explain in a bit more detail what you are asking. Jesus quotes a text. The English bible has chapters and verses. Some bibles have information in the margin. What is it you wish to know ?

Comment: see wikipedia and bible dot org for basic history

Comment: It seems that, for at least a millennium, being in latin or greek, the bible was not very available to people in general.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed, not because it isn't a good question (the answer is something those interested in the Bible should be aware of), but because it has an answer that could easily have been found in the obvious places.
For instance, read this article: [Chapters and verses of the Bible - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible).
It was the first result returned when I entered the Title question into Google search.

Comment: @fp says "*It seems that, for at least a millennium, being in latin or greek, the bible was not very available to people in general.*".  Until Gutenberg's printing press people in general had no access other than the word of the priests etc., and even then it took a long time before the Church allowed local language translations, with those that dared often ending up executed for heresy ([Censorship of the Bible - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_the_Bible)).

Comment: @Ray Butterworth Thank you, my question is answered by your references.

Comment: @fp Sorry no one welcomed you to the group before you got told to look it up yourself etc. So welcome! Don't shy away from asking future questions. In the meantime please take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the group.

Answer (score 1):

> Stephen Langton, in the 12th century, added what we use today as the
> chapter divisions. He did this into the Latin Vulgate. The tradition
> is that these divisions were later transfered to the Hebrew Bible.
> From manuscripts dating back to the fourth century, however, some form
> of chapter divisions were used. In 1551, Robert Estienne (a.k.a.
> Stephanus) added verse divisions to his fourth edition of the Greek
> New Testament, while en route between Paris and Lyons, France. The
> first translation to employ his versification was the Geneva
> translation of 1557 (whole Bible, 1560).

Taken from Bible.org.

Comment: In my notes on this (from the Trinitarian Bible Society) the date for Stephen Langton starting chapter divisions is given as 1228. For Stephanus, the dates for verses agrees. Interesting about 4th century MSS!